# Generate rules via LESS plugin

Tags: less

I'd like to write a plugin that can generate a LESS function named `alt` that can do the following transformation:

```
.button {
    background-color: alt(red, blue);
    color: alt(black, white);
}
```

And output the following:

```
.button {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    body.alt & {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be much documentation about writing LESS plugins on the site, so hoping someone can provide an example of how this might be written :) Thanks!

Comment: You write a (preeval) visitor plugin that takes rulesets and depending on presence of `alt` calls in its rules appends `body.alt &` ruleset there by copying the outer ruleset w/o properties not containing `alt` and `alt` replaced with `altalt` (then `alt` to return its first parameter and `altalt` the second). There's various methods of doing something like this, and details may very.

Answer (score 1):

I think a mixin would be best for this. Something like the following LESS:

```
.alt(@property, @primary-color, @alternate-color) {
  @{property}: @primary-color;
  body.alt & {
    @{property}: @alternate-color;
  }
}

.button {
  .alt(background-color, red, blue);
  .alt(color, black, white);
}
```

Which will compile to the following CSS:

```
.button {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}
body.alt .button {
  background-color: blue;
}
body.alt .button {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: I was actually toying with something similar to this :) My main reservation with using mixins is the duplicate `body.alt` selectors, but there may be no way to avoid it.

Comment: @Сhris *the duplicate body.alt selectors* - it's never a problem since any descent css-minifier (that everybody must use these days) is able to merge such duplicates just fine.